# Count returns zero when placed inside a loop Using PYTHON

Tags: python

I have written a code that should display the folder name and file count inside the folder. The code works fine when keeping outside a loop but returns me count as zero when I keep the code inside the loop

```py
root = 'C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Logs_of_Hell'
count_of_file = 0

import pathlib
noOfFiles = local_time_of_oldest = local_time_of_newest= 0
subdir=""
N = 0

def get():
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        N_c = len(files)
        user = {}
        user['filepath'] = path
        user['count'] = N_c

        print("Printing first User")
        print(user) # prints  {'filepath': 'C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Logs_of_Hell\\results\\0', 'count': 3}

        print("second")
        for name in subdirs:
            print(user)# prints  {'filepath': 'C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Logs_of_Hell\\results\\0', 'count': 0}
            #.....
```

so here it works fine and gives me the correct count on the first print and gives me zero counts on the second. am able to retrieve the file path, but the value of count turns to zero. I tried debugging giving a static value that works fine on both prints, but when I try using it like this, the count value turns zero on the second print. Can anyone explain to me why am not able to get the count value on the second loop

this is output am observing , even though i use the same dict variable na , the value is different for both prints :

```
{'filepath': 'C:/Users/Logs_of_Hell\\pabot_results', 'count': 0}
second
{'filepath': 'C:/Users/Logs_of_Hell\\pabot_results', 'count': 0}
second

Printing first User
{'filepath': 'C:/Users/Logs_of_Hell\\pabot_results\\0', 'count': 3}
Printing first User
{'filepath': 'C:/Users/Logs_of_Hell\\pabot_results\\1', 'count': 3}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Tried Editing Code :

```
import os
import time
import glob
root = 'C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Logs_of_Hell'
count_of_file = 0

import pathlib
noOfFiles = local_time_of_oldest = local_time_of_newest= 0
subdir=""
N = 0
nextone ={}

def get():
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        N_c = len(files)
        user = {}
        user['filepath'] = path
        user['count'] = N_c
        # print(N_c)
        print(user)

        for name in subdirs:
            print(user)
            # # print(os.path.join(path, name))
            subdir = os.path.join(path, name)
            if(os.path.isdir(subdir)):
                taggedrootdir = pathlib.Path(subdir)
                oldest_file = (min([f for f in taggedrootdir.resolve().glob('**/*') if f.is_file()], key=os.path.getmtime))
                newest_file = (max([f for f in taggedrootdir.resolve().glob('**/*') if f.is_file()], key=os.path.getmtime))

                c_time_of_oldest = os.path.getctime(oldest_file)
                local_time_of_oldest = time.ctime(c_time_of_oldest)

                c_time_of_newest = os.path.getctime(newest_file)
                local_time_of_newest = time.ctime(c_time_of_newest)
                nextone['filepath'] = subdir
                nextone['newest'] = local_time_of_newest
                nextone['oldest'] = local_time_of_oldest
                # print(nextone)
                mrgDict = mergeDict(user, nextone) # performing merging
```

but the second print only prints the last value

Comment: You are missing a quotation mark (') on line 1

Comment: i think that happened while copying the code from IDE @QWERTYL

Comment: Are you sure the path has greater than 0 files and the path is not changing?

Comment: filepath changes according to files inside Logs_of_Hell @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer

Comment: Please show us your complete output.  It should not be possible from the code you show us for the first and second calls to `print` to print different things, because you don't change any value inside `user` between the two calls.  After the second call, you might be changing the value in code you aren't showing us.

Comment: Try declaring N_C var outside the function.

Comment: Added Output @CryptoFool

Comment: Are you expecting the folders to be included in the file count?  Because 0 is the correct answer for `{'filepath': 'C:/Users/Logs_of_Hell\\pabot_results', 'count': 0}`

Comment: You should also post the actual code that you are running.  This snip isn't enough.

Comment: No i don want the folders to be included @shrewmouse , i want it to be the same way as i got while printing it first .

Comment: this is the actual code am running currently and it's not the snip @shrewmouse

Comment: So what's the problem?  Your output is the correct answer assuming that there are three files in `C:/Users/Logs_of_Hell\\pabot_results\\1` and `C:/Users/Logs_of_Hell\\pabot_results\\0`

Comment: Kindy check the output clearly , am printing the same variable two times , "second" and "Printing first User" but both of them is printing me two different values . i want the second loop also to print same as first loop since i have to perform certain action based on that count in second loop @shrewmouse

Comment: I don't understand what you're showing us.  How is it possible that `second` prints before `Printing first User`.  That isn't possible from this code.  There's something you aren't showing us.

Comment: ...ok, with new code it's possible to get the output you're getting.  I guess that's where the output came from.

Comment: There is no way that the output that you posted came from the code that you supplied.  How could "second" come before "Printing first User"?

Comment: from code edited , am only able to retrieve the last dictionary value , but not others . I want that 2 dictionary value to be displayed @CryptoFool

Comment: Are you trying to build a dictionary like this?  `{'./Logs/1': {'count': 3}, './Logs/0': {'count': 3}, './Logs': {'count': 0}}`?  Are you perhaps confused by the order of keys in a dictionary?  Because dictionary keys are not guaranteed to be ordered in any specific way.  The first item you put in the dict could appear after the second item that you put in the dict.

Comment: No arrangement is not at all a problem , i just want the same thing in ur answer to be printed after that loop , so that i can combine the value with another dictionary , or i just wanted the user to be returned to other function so that i can merge it with other dictionary @shrewmouse

Comment: @AuroraEugene, the last code block in my answer shows you how to do that.

Comment: but if i use like that , how am i going to merge it with the other dictionary @shrewmouse

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you meant to make `get` a recursive function.

```
import os

root = './Logs'
count_of_file = 0

import pathlib
noOfFiles = local_time_of_oldest = local_time_of_newest= 0
subdir=""
N = 0

def get(root):
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        N_c = len(files)
        user = {}
        user['filepath'] = path
        user['count'] = N_c

        print("Printing first User")
        print(user) # prints  {'filepath': 'C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Logs_of_Hell\\results\\0', 'count': 3}

        print("second")
        for name in subdirs:
            get(name)

get(root)
~
```

What output do you expect from the following directory structure?

```
[root@sri-0000-0001 sandbox]# tree Logs/
Logs/
├── 0
│   ├── log1
│   ├── log2
│   └── log3
└── 1
    ├── log1
    ├── log2
    └── log3

2 directories, 6 files
```

Output:

```
[root@sri-0000-0001 sandbox]# python test.py
Printing first User
{'count': 0, 'filepath': './Logs'}
second
Printing first User
{'count': 3, 'filepath': './Logs/1'}
second
Printing first User
{'count': 3, 'filepath': './Logs/0'}
second
```

If you are trying to stuff info all into the same dict then you need to modify the same dict every time through the recursion.

```
import os

root = './Logs'
count_of_file = 0

import pathlib
noOfFiles = local_time_of_oldest = local_time_of_newest= 0
subdir=""
N = 0


counts={}

def get(root):
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        N_c = len(files)
        user = {}
        counts[path]={}
        counts[path]['count']=N_c
        #user['filepath'] = path
        #user['count'] = N_c

        #print("Printing first User")
        #print(user) # prints  {'filepath': 'C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Logs_of_Hell\\results\\0', 'count': 3}

        for name in subdirs:
            get(name)

get(root)

print(counts)
```

Which would give you:

```
[root@sri-0000-0001 sandbox]# python test.py
{'./Logs/1': {'count': 3}, './Logs/0': {'count': 3}, './Logs': {'count': 0}}
```

**Not using a global:**

```
import os

root = './Logs'
count_of_file = 0

import pathlib
noOfFiles = local_time_of_oldest = local_time_of_newest= 0
subdir=""
N = 0



def get(root):
    counts={}
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
        N_c = len(files)
        user = {}
        counts[path]={}
        counts[path]['count']=N_c
        #user['filepath'] = path
        #user['count'] = N_c

        #print("Printing first User")
        #print(user) # prints  {'filepath': 'C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Logs_of_Hell\\results\\0', 'count': 3}

        for name in subdirs:
            counts.update(get(name))

    return counts

counts=get(root)

print(counts)
```

Comment: So what if i wanted to return the value of user to someother function ,where i can combine user with another dictionaries . that was the reason why i wanted to print user inside "for name in subdirs:" , so that i can directly combine . since i didn't complete the programming of second dictionary , and it is of no use if i don't get user printed

Comment: Do you want an array of dictionaries?  Or a one big dict indexed by the path?

Comment: I updated the code , with merging , so i wanted to merge this user with "nextone" , for doing that i want the user dict to be visible inside that for loop

Comment: @AuroraEugene `mrgDict .update(nextone)` , but that is just going to overwrite the entries in mrgDict with nextone.  Exactly what output are you expecting?  It's not clear what you want your program to output.  Please give an example.

Comment: i guess u understood what i wanted in user dict , it is same as u are thinking , i want the foldername and filecount on user dict . secondly , i wanted to merge this "user" with "nextone" which is another dictionary with common key "filepath" and extra key  modified dates of new and old file inside a folder ,  so that i can get a new dict with foldername , count , oldmodified date and new modified date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229784/discussion-between-shrewmouse-and-aurora-eugene).

Comment: I have explained with an example , can u please check that out and help me

Answer (score 0):

Actually that was quite simple code , i think i confused my self with lot of requirements . So what i did was instead of using multiple loops i used single loop and pushed it to a dictionary .